# Magento 2.2 : How To Specify External Library/Dependency In Your Custom Magento Module Deployed under the app/code folder

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, composer

I have a (Not Open-Source) custom Magento 2.2x module that I'm working on, that has a dependency on an external composer package (*bugsnag/bugsnag*)

Here's how my project is currently structured:

**Current Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

**File - module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Gsd_Test" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**File - composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "gsd/test",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "php": "7.*",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag":"^3.0"
    },
    "suggest": {

    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": [

    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Gsd\\Test\\": "",
            "Bugsnag\\" : "vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Gsd/Test"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Controller - Gsd\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Gsd\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
        $bugsnag = \Bugsnag\Client::make('XXXXXX');
        \Bugsnag\Handler::register($bugsnag);

        $bugsnag->notifyException("Testing ");
    }

}
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gsd_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

BUT, attempting to access that Controller (http://m22.localhost.net/admin/gsdtest/index/index) results in the following error:

[image: Application Error]

Looks like, for whatever reason, the Autoloader ignores the content within the `app/code/Gsd/Test/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src` folder at run-time.

(Ironically, PhpStorm doesn't report any error during development per se)

Now, if I add "bugsnag/bugsnag" as a composer dependency at the MAGENTO_HOME folder level, i.e, if I run the following commands:

```
cd $MAGENTO_HOME
composer require bugsnag/bugsnag 3.*
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

then my controller works just fine.

So, my questions are:

- I recall this used to work on Magento 2.1x (i.e. having the composer dependency inside the module specific composer.json) about 2 - 3 months back. But, it no longer works on Magento 2.1x or Magento 2.2x ... What changed??
- Is there a way to specify module specific composer.json dependencies? If not - how can one "ship" a custom-module - that has dependencies on 3rd party libraries - so that it can be deployed directly into the `app/code` folder?
  ( Requiring customers deploy the module using composer may not work for all businesses/situations )

Answer (score 1):

If you want require dependencies with composer then your module must be installed as a composer module. At the moment it is not, just files in app/code so the solution is to develop core and public it on your packagist then write magento wrapper in app/code or add all dependencies in composer.json in root so you will be able to use them in your module in app/code. For obvious reasons the first approach is much better and recommended.

Comment: So - outside of deploying the module as a public module on packagist/github - there isn't a way to ship out a "fully-self-contained" 3rd party module in Magento 2x ??

Comment: Not even a github, composer is a core dependencies manager for magento and "github way" or "copy/past code m1 style" will not work. Therefore your answer is correct. Unless you will do some "no-magento" way modules with private composer scope and so on but it does not make any sense.